# Is there a set-theoretic proof of Induction on the complexity of formulae?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, induction, set-theory, propositional-calculus

The Induction on the complexity of formulae is a theorem on the syntax of PL that states the following:

*Suppose an arbitrary property holds for all atomic formulae in PL, and, if it holds for A and B, then it holds for (¬A), (A∨B), (A∧B), (A→B) and (A↔B). Then this property holds for all formulae on PL.*

I've seen many intuitive and "classic" demonstrations on this theorem, but is there a purely set-theoretic proof on this theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by a "purely set theoretic proof" and what do you hope to get from it?

Comment: This is induction on a well-founded tree (or [well-founded induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction)), but even simpler, because the trees are finitely branching.

Comment: Is a proof method used to prove theorems stating properties of formulas or derivations.

Comment: In set theory we can prove Induction in its general form.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049555/how-can-a-proof-by-formula-induction-in-a-formal-language-be-formalized) as well as the post [Understanding Structural Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483045/understanding-structural-induction)

Comment: See also [Induction on complexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922010/induction-on-complexity-upside-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [well-founded induction principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation#Induction_and_recursion) says the following: If you have a well-founded relation $<$ on a set $X$ (that is there is no infinitely long decreasing chain $x_1 > x_2 > x_3 > \ldots$), then given a proposition $\phi(x)$ on $x\in X$,
$$(\forall x.(\forall y < x. \phi(y))\to\phi(x))\to(\forall x.\phi(x)).$$
This can be proved in set theory.

Now in the case of a finitely branching trees, let $X$ be the set of possible trees (or terms in your case), and let $x < y$ if $x$ is a subtree (or subterm) of $y$. This relation is well-founded, and the corresponding induction principle obtained from the above is called [structural-induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction).